# Facebook App users on Google map

Tags: php, facebook

I need to create a Google map that would display all my app users. The problem is, that that Facebook doesn't seem to provide enough information to do that, country at most. I'd like to display user position on map at least to the proximity of the city.

The only option I see, is to track user's location using their IP. What are the other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has provided it, you can get their current location (city, state, country) by prompting for the 'user_location' and/or 'friends_location' permissions.

You might also want to check out the 'user_checkins' and/or 'friends_checkins' permissions for more timely and accurate locations.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Or as a fallback, like you say, you can usually get an approximate location by their IP. But that's not always very accurate.